# How to restrict a while loop in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop

I have created program called Single Lane Bridge using threads where A single-lane bridge connects North Village and South Village. Farmers in the two villages use this bridge to deliver their produce to the neighbouring town. The bridge can become deadlocked if both a northbound and a southbound farmer get on the bridge at the same time (farmers in these villages are stubborn and are unable to back up).

**I am trying two restrict the number of framers that being create to only 2. And once both farmer have crossed I want the program to end. At the moment the program keep running,**

Here is my solution to the above problem.

```
    package threading.practice;

import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class SingleLaneBridge {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final Bridge bridge = new Bridge();

        Thread thNorthbound = new Thread( new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                while(true)
                {
                    Farmer farmer = new Farmer(bridge);
                    Thread th = new Thread(farmer);
                    farmer.setName("North Farmer 1");
                    th.start();
                   /**
                    * this method each farmer will go to sleep for 10 microw secounds
                    */
                    try
                    {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long)(Math.random()*10));
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException iex)
                    {
                        iex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        });


        /**
         * This method create a new thread called the NortFramer
         * Secound 
         */
        Thread thSouthbound = new Thread( new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                while(true)
                {
                    Farmer farmer = new Farmer(bridge);
                    Thread th = new Thread(farmer);
                    farmer.setName("South Farmer 2");
                    th.start();
                    try
                    {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long)(Math.random()*10));
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException iex)
                    {
                        iex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        thNorthbound.start();
        thSouthbound.start();
    }

}

class Bridge
{
    private final Semaphore semaphore;

    public Bridge()
    {
        semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    }
    public void crossBridge(Farmer farmer)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.printf(" %s is trying to cross the bridge.\n",farmer.getName());
            semaphore.acquire();
            System.out.printf("%s is crossing the bridge.\n",farmer.getName());
            long duration = (long)(Math.random() * 10);
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(duration);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException iex)
        {
            iex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.printf("Farmer %s has crossed the bridge.\n",farmer.getName());
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }
}

class Farmer implements Runnable
{
    private String name;
    private Bridge bridge;

    public Farmer(Bridge bridge)
    {
        this.bridge = bridge;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        bridge.crossBridge(this);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you expect the program to ever end with while(true)-loops? Basically you keep generating the farmers, they are all just named "North Farmer 1" or "South Farmer 1".

Comment: While is basically executing as long as the expression inside it is true: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html You could use a counter and check if its above a certain value for instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is modification that keeps track of all farmers crossing the bridge.

```
package multithreading1;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SingleLaneBridge {

    // count of all farmers
    private volatile static int count = 0;
    // variable used for synchronization in multiple threads
    private static final Integer max_count = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Bridge bridge = new Bridge();

        Thread thNorthbound = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (true) {
                    Farmer farmer = new Farmer(bridge);
                    // tracking count of farmers in multiple threads
                    synchronized (max_count) {
                        count++;
                        if (count > max_count)
                            break;
                        farmer.setName("North Farmer " + count);
                    }

                    Thread th = new Thread(farmer);
                    th.start();

                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 10));
                    } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                        iex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        Thread thSouthbound = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (true) {
                    Farmer farmer = new Farmer(bridge);
                    // tracking count of farmers in multiple threads
                    synchronized (max_count) {
                        count++;
                        if (count > max_count)
                            break;
                        farmer.setName("South Farmer " + count);
                    }

                    Thread th = new Thread(farmer);
                    th.start();

                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 10));
                    } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                        iex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        thNorthbound.start();
        thSouthbound.start();
    }

}
```